# How to append c# variable in src tag of script in MVC razor template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
   @{
       string clientId = "1234567"

      <script id="AbcClient" src="https://myspecialjs/@clientId/client.js" type="text/javascript" 
      async></script>
   }
```

How do I append variable "`clientId`" in `src tag after "myspecialjs/`" ?

This is an MVC razor template.

Comment: Is there a reason why your script tag is within the `@{ ... }` brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{
    string clientId = "1234567";
    string url = "https://myspecialjs/" + clientId + "/client.js";
    <script id="AbcClient" src=@url type="text/javascript" 
    async></script>
    @url
}
```